# Moving the intro image before the article info (protostar template)

Tags: php, joomla

I'm working on a website with Joomla 3.2.1 and the Protostar template.
I want the article image to be shown before the article info. The order I want is the following one:

1. article title
2. intro image
3. article info
4. article intro

I tried doing it changing the code on template.css, but it also moves the article info of articles with no intro image, so it isn't a good option for me.

I tried changing the .php files. For example, the default_item.php of the featured articles view. I copied the intro image's code, and pasted it over the article info's code, but the article info is still being shown over the intro image.

What can I do to put the intro image over the article info?

Here is the code for the article items file (default_item.php) in the featured articles page.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_content
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Create a shortcut for params.
$params = &$this->item->params;
$images = json_decode($this->item->images);
$canEdit = $this->item->params->get('access-edit');
$info    = $this->item->params->get('info_block_position', 0);

?>

<?php if ($this->item->state == 0) : ?>
    <div class="system-unpublished">
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
    <h2 class="item-title">
    <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && $params->get('access-view')) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>"> <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?></a>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($this->item->state == 0) : ?>
    <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo JText::_('JUNPUBLISHED'); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($params->get('show_print_icon') || $params->get('show_email_icon') || $canEdit) : ?>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right"> <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"> <span class="icon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php if ($params->get('show_print_icon')) : ?>
            <li class="print-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_popup', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
            <li class="email-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.email', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($canEdit) : ?>
            <li class="edit-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php // Todo Not that elegant would be nice to group the params ?>
<?php $useDefList = ($params->get('show_modify_date') || $params->get('show_publish_date') || $params->get('show_create_date')
    || $params->get('show_hits') || $params->get('show_category') || $params->get('show_parent_category') || $params->get('show_author') ); ?>

<?php if ($useDefList && ($info == 0 ||  $info == 2)) : ?>
    <dl class="article-info  muted">
        <dt class="article-info-term">
        <?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_INFO'); ?>
        </dt>

        <?php if ($params->get('show_author') && !empty($this->item->author )) : ?>
            <dd class="createdby">
                <?php $author = $this->item->author; ?>
                <?php $author = ($this->item->created_by_alias ? $this->item->created_by_alias : $author); ?>
                <?php if (!empty($this->item->contactid ) && $params->get('link_author') == true) : ?>
                    <?php
                    echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY',
                        JHtml::_('link', JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id='.$this->item->contactid), $author)
                    ); ?>
                <?php else :?>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY', $author); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($params->get('show_parent_category') && !empty($this->item->parent_slug)) : ?>
            <dd class="parent-category-name">
                <?php $title = $this->escape($this->item->parent_title);
                $url = '<a href="'.JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->parent_slug)).'">'.$title.'</a>';?>
                <?php if ($params->get('link_parent_category') && !empty($this->item->parent_slug)) : ?>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $url); ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $title); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($params->get('show_category')) : ?>
            <dd class="category-name">
                <?php $title = $this->escape($this->item->category_title);
                $url = '<a href="'.JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->catslug)).'">'.$title.'</a>';?>
                <?php if ($params->get('link_category') && $this->item->catslug) : ?>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY', $url); ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY', $title); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($params->get('show_publish_date')) : ?>
            <dd class="published">
                <span class="icon-calendar"></span> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->publish_up, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($info == 0) : ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('show_modify_date')) : ?>
                <dd class="modified">
                <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
                <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_LAST_UPDATED', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->modified, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($params->get('show_create_date')) : ?>
                <dd class="create">
                    <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($params->get('show_hits')) : ?>
                <dd class="hits">
                    <span class="icon-eye-open"></span>
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_HITS', $this->item->hits); ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </dl>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (isset($images->image_intro) && !empty($images->image_intro)) : ?>
    <?php $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_intro)) ? $params->get('float_intro') : $images->float_intro; ?>
    <div class="pull-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?> item-image"> <img
    <?php if ($images->image_intro_caption):
        echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption) .'"';
    endif; ?>
    src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/> </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (!$params->get('show_intro')) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayTitle; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?> <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>

<?php if ($useDefList && ($info == 1 ||  $info == 2)) : ?>
    <dl class="article-info muted">
        <dt class="article-info-term">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_INFO'); ?>
        </dt>
        <?php if ($info == 1) : ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('show_author') && !empty($this->item->author )) : ?>
                <dd class="createdby">
                    <?php $author = $this->item->author; ?>
                    <?php $author = ($this->item->created_by_alias ? $this->item->created_by_alias : $author); ?>
                    <?php if (!empty($this->item->contactid ) && $params->get('link_author') == true) : ?>
                        <?php
                        echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY',
                            JHtml::_('link', JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id='.$this->item->contactid), $author)
                        ); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY', $author); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($params->get('show_parent_category') && !empty($this->item->parent_slug)) : ?>
                <dd class="parent-category-name">
                    <?php   $title = $this->escape($this->item->parent_title);
                    $url = '<a href="'.JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->parent_slug)).'">'.$title.'</a>';?>
                    <?php if ($params->get('link_parent_category') && $this->item->parent_slug) : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $url); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $title); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($params->get('show_category')) : ?>
                <dd class="category-name">
                    <?php $title = $this->escape($this->item->category_title);
                    $url = '<a href="'.JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->catslug)).'">'.$title.'</a>';?>
                    <?php if ($params->get('link_category') && $this->item->catslug) : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY', $url); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY', $title); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($params->get('show_publish_date')) : ?>
                <dd class="published">
                    <span class="icon-calendar"></span> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->publish_up, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($params->get('show_create_date')) : ?>
            <dd class="create">
                <span class="icon-calendar"></span> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($params->get('show_modify_date')) : ?>
            <dd class="modified">
                <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
                <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_LAST_UPDATED', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->modified, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($params->get('show_hits')) : ?>
            <dd class="hits">
                <span class="icon-eye-open"></span> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_HITS', $this->item->hits); ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </dl>

    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_tags', 1)) : ?>
        <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($params->get('show_readmore') && $this->item->readmore) :
    if ($params->get('access-view')) :
        $link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid));
    else :
        $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
        $active = $menu->getActive();
        $itemId = $active->id;
        $link1 = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&Itemid=' . $itemId);
        $returnURL = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid));
        $link = new JUri($link1);
        $link->setVar('return', base64_encode($returnURL));
    endif; ?>

    <p class="readmore"><a class="btn" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"> <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>

    <?php if (!$params->get('access-view')) :
        echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_REGISTER_TO_READ_MORE');
    elseif ($readmore = $this->item->alternative_readmore) :
        echo $readmore;
        if ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) != 0) :
        echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
        endif;
    elseif ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) == 0) :
        echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE_TITLE');
    else :
        echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE');
        echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
    endif; ?>

    </a></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($this->item->state == 0) : ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayContent; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Have you tried to override the template?](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x%3aHow_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides)

Please read the documentation on the link above. They also give examples of the template you just mentioned, for example editing the html/com_content/article/default.php.

Comment: I already do that. The point is that some changes I do in the overrides work fine, but I can't get this one done.

Comment: I edited the post and added the code of the php file that adds articles in the 'featured articles' view.